# How to animate rows in UITableView on its loading?

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I want to use UITableViewRowAnimation with :reloadData.

Before i used that example for Table loading (I found that in some ios dev guide):

```c
for (NSDictionary *entry in [dl reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        int insertIdx = 0;

        [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    }
```

But that way seems to be really slow on big data, so how to fast load tableviews with animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. Within these two commands you can update/remove/insert rows and have them animated for you. It's also much more efficient than using `reloadData`.

More on this topic here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Quick excerpt:

> - (void)beginUpdates
>
> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and
>   selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and
>   indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously. This group of
>   methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates. These method
>   pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and
>   selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count
>   might become invalid. You should not call reloadData within the group;
>   if you call this method within the group, you will need to perform any
>   animations yourself.

Comment: So, i must to use somethink like `[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];` where indexPaths is all indexes in table?

Answer (score 0):

Wasabii is right, but in your case you could accumulate all indexes in array, then update table with one insert command:

```
NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

for (NSDictionary *entry in [dl reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    int insertIdx = 0;

    [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
    [indexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]];
}

// insert rows into table
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```